# Thrift Struct equivalent for the JSON Schema

Tags: thrift

Say, I wanted to get the equivalent Thrift Struct for following

```
{
    "xyz": {
        "oneOf": [
            {
                "type": "null"
            },
            {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "abd": {
                        "type" :"string"
                    },
                    "dfs": {
                        "type": "string",
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So, here, there is a struct xyz which can be null or which can have two properties "abd" and "dfs". I thought of using union for this purpose but with that problem is I have to create the object for "abd" and "dfs". So, it would be something like:-

```
union XYZ {
   1: SomeStruct someStruct
}

struct SomeStruct {
    1: optional string abd
    2: optional string dfs
}
```

Now, the problem with this is it now expects that there is some key "someStruct" that it should get inside xyz. And hence this is not exact equivalent of what I need.

Can someone please suggest some good way to that?

Comment: The `union` does not make much sense, if you have only one member. It is not strictly wrong though, but the poin of a `union` is to have **multiple** options where only one is exclusively used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, the two cases of "oneOf" refer to what an xyz could be: either `null`, or an non-null valid instance with some (optional) data.

```
struct XYZ {
    1: optional string abd
    2: optional string dfs
}


struct UsesXyz {
    1: optional Xyx
}
```

The `null` case is where instances of `UsesXyz` don't set the member. In other words, the `null` case is not reflected in the *declaration* of Xyz, but how it is *used*.